# For NA in one column; cannot change factor levels of another column

Tags: r

The problem seems too simple to be even put up here; but I can't find a solution that works. I have a data frame (`df`) of 3 columns; of which one is a factor column (`df$Colors`) with 3 levels ("Blue","Red" and "Black"). In another column (`df$Outliers`) are numeric values some of which are "NA". I want to add another column (say `df$NewColors`) similar to `df$Colors` where for "NA" in `df$Outliers`, `df$NewColors = "Orange"`. 
I added an additional level as follows :

```
 > levels(df$Colors) <- c(levels(df$Colors), "Orange")
```

However the new added column seems to be using old "Color" values instead of replacing it by "Orange" where it should.Also it generates integer values for factors of `df$Colors` but I want to keep the old categorical variable.
The code I used is as follows:

```
>levels(df$Color) <- c(levels(df$Color),"Orange")

> for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$NewColors[i] <- ifelse (is.na(df$Outliers[i]), "Orange", df$Colors[i]) 
  }
```

Where am I going wrong?
Here is the sample data :

```
> BodyLength <- rep(seq(1,9),2)
> Colors <- rep(c("Black","Blue","Red"),6)
> Outliers <- c(seq(1,8),"NA",seq(1,8),"NA")
> df <- data.frame(BodyLength,Colors,Outliers)
```

Comment: "NA" is different from NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
df$Colors_new <- df$Colors
levels(df$Colors_new) <- c(levels(df$Colors_new),"Orange")
df$Colors_new[which(df$Outliers == "NA")] <- "Orange"
```

Note that your NA are not real NAs but rather text that says NA. To do it properly sample data must be:

```
Outliers <- c(seq(1,8),NA,seq(1,8),NA)
```

Then you could use:

```
df$Colors_new[is.na(df$Outliers)] <- "Orange"
```

Comment: Works like a charm...leaving me feel like a fool! Thanks @JonGrub

Comment: You don't need to. Asking questions is the way I learned this :) Btw: If you like my answer, would you accept it, please?

Answer (score 0):

As @joel.wilson mentions your data example is incorrect in that it gives the character "NA" instead of a missing value (NA). If that's causing the issue you could adjust this using the following:

```
df$Outliers[which(df$Outliers=="NA")]<-NA
```

Apart from that, something like this should work for what you are trying to achieve:

```
df$new.colors<-ifelse(is.na(df$Outliers),"Orange",as.character(df$Colors))
```

returns "Orange" if df$Outliers is NA, and otherwise returns df$Colors.
Use `as.factor` to make this new variable a factor again.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment `NA` is not `"NA"`. If you have `"NA"` your outliers are treated as character data as the numeric values are coerced. In addition `is.na("NA")` returns FALSE. If your `NA` is appropriately treated your code should be ok. You could also consider using `replace` as an alternative to a loop.

```
BodyLength <- rep(seq(1,9),2)
Colors <- rep(c("Black","Blue","Red"),6)
Outliers <- c(seq(1,8),NA,seq(1,8),NA)
df <- data.frame(BodyLength,Colors,Outliers)
df$newColors = df$Colors
levels(df$newColors) = c(levels(df$Colors),"Orange")
df$newColors = replace(df$newColors,is.na(df$Outliers),"Orange")
```

If you intended to have outliers as characters, with value `"NA"`, then `is.na` should be replaced with `df$Outliers == "NA"`